# Location of web resources in HTML5 + REST project?

Tags: eclipse, html, rest, jakarta-ee, jboss6.x

I am learning HTML5 integration with REST web services.
Using information mentioned at URL:
[Redhat tutorial for HTML5 app](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Web_Framework_Kit/2.4/html/Getting_Started_with_an_OpenShift_Project/chap-Getting_Started_with_an_HTML5_Project_on_OpenShift.html%20URL)

I created sample application in my eclipse workspace. Generated code structure is as shown below:

[image]

I do not understand why all web resources are stored are shown as a deployed resources? Does not it mean that, they are not part of my source code? I thought there would WEB-INF directory, under which my web resources will be stored. Please correct my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is just the way eclipse displays the structure of workspace. But in actual file system, web resources are stored under:
src/main/webapp